# Pulling data from from a dataframe in pandas using size method

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Okay, I am working on a data project and realized, that by using the size() method I happen to get exactly what I need. First, a little background, I am doing a project on terrorism and want to get the number of attacks, in each country by year. I have the year part done. I also found out that by using the Size method I will get each country listed and the number of attacks. (The amount that each country appears in that specific list is also the number of attacks in that country for each year.)

So I have the following line of code which will give me all the country names in one column and in the second column the number of attacks:

```
group = first_year.groupby(first_year.Country).size()
```

when I run this I get the following:

```
Country       
Afghanistan          6
Algeria              42
Bangladesh           6
.
.
.
dtype: int64
```

This is what I want but what I want to do is go through each column and push them into an array. I can figure the array part out. What I cannot figure out is how to grab 'Afghanistan' or 6 or 'Algeria'. So I have tried the following:

```
print(group[0:1])
```

and that will get me:

```
Country
Afghanistan    6
dtype: int64
```

Again, I want to target the 'Afghanistan' or the '6' ONLY. I then tried using the .iat method and got the following error: ValueError: iAt based indexing can only have integer indexers

the .size method gets me exactly what I want! But I have a feeling that it is not the tool for my job. Any help would be appreciated! Have a great day

Comment: Mike, does `group.reset_index().values` get you the array you want?

Comment: Bob Haffner YES!!! I think that does. Wel,l it gives me one big list it appears but I can do group.reset_index().values[0][0] which will get me the values that I want! I just will create a loop to go through each value and push the country into one list and the deaths in another! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, if you want two lists you could do `group.index` and then `group.values`

Comment: Also, just trying to put myself in your shoes, `group.to_dict()` might be handier than two lists

Comment: Yes, those will work as well but you just got me over this big hurdle Bob and thank you! This was literally the 'hardest' part of my project for me! Thank you again!